# Почему выводит это, а не то что ожидаю (не понимаю по наследованию )

Tags: java

```
public class Test {
     public static void main(String[] args) {
           new Person().printPerson();
           new Student().printPerson();
     }
}

class Student extends Person {
     private String getInfo() {
           return "Student";
     }
}

class Person {
     private String getInfo() {
           return "Person";
     }

     public void printPerson() {
           System.out.println(getInfo());
     }  
}
```

Выводит

```
    Person
    Person
```

Я не понимаю, почему второе слово не Student. Похоже, что-нибудь связанное с динамическим связыванием (подпункт про это xD).

Мои рассуждения (по второму объекту):

Мы создаем объект класса Student и выполняем метод printPerson(). Данный метод printPerson() унаследован с класса Person. Унаследованный метод printPerson() в классе Student вызывает  метод getInfo() из класса Student (*?на самом деле почему-то из класса Person*). Метод getInfo() из класса должен возвратить "Student", и соответственно должно отобразиться Student.

Answer (score 6):

Потому что приватные методы не переопределяются. (не могут быть override)

Comment: `public void printPerson() {
           System.out.println(getInfo());
     } `
Этот метод НЕ видит никаких других методов, кроме `Person#getInfo()`. Не видит он других. и  не может даже знать о них.

Comment: приватные методы **являются** финальными. Чтобы проще было понять.

Comment: Нужно использовать protected

Comment: @argamidon, то есть если бы было протектед, он бы вывел student?

Comment: Что-то я опять у меня возник вопрос по этому примеру. Вот он:

Метод getInfo() в классе Person имеет модификатор доступа private. Каким образом у нас получается обратиться к нему из подкласса Student?

Comment: `class Student extends Person {
     private String getInfo() {
           return "Student";
     }
}
`
Я здесь не вижу обращений к приватному методу.

Comment: @panzermarin, у нас не получается к нему обратиться, потому что он private и за пределами класса, в котором он был объявлен, к нему обратиться нельзя.

p.s. не знал, что в яве разрешены такие штуки. Чтобы компилятор надавал по рукам за такое, надо ставить `@Override`?

Comment: @Etki Override необязательная аннотация. А какие штуки удивляют? нужно чуть поучить, чуть привыкнуть, чуть наступить на свои грабли. И глядишь - профессионал :)

@panzermarin http://www.quizful.net/test/java_se_basic на, пройди пару тестов для начального уровня. таких вопросов там уйма вместе с объяснениями.

Comment: @argamidon, я знаю, что необязательный, я спрашиваю, как такие штуки отловить на этапе компиляции?

Comment: argamidon, ты, похоже, не понял, в чем мой вопрос, и отвечаешь не на то, что меня интересует.
Еще раз (смотри не мельком):    
1. Метод getInfo() в классе Person имеет модификатор private. Почему мы имеем возможность обратиться к данному методу из класса Student? То, что мы обращаемся именно к нему, следует из выводимой строки.  
2. Почему при отображении второй строки (см. исходный вопрос) вызывается метод getInfo() из класса Person, а не из класса Student? Ведь метод getInfo() в классе Student имеет такое же имя и одинаковую сигнатуру.

 Etki, может ты что скажешь?

Comment: @panzermarin Это все потому что метод printPerson вызывается из базового класса. И соответственно поиск метода getInfo() начинается сверху вниз. А так как метод getInfo() для базового класса один(метод getInfo() в классе Student - это совсем другой метод), то он выводит надпись Person.

Comment: Ладно. Я совсем запутался. Вот цитата из книги: "Dynamic binding works as follows: Suppose an object o is an instance of classes C1, C2,..,
Cn-1, and Cn, where C1 is a subclass of C2, C2 is a subclass of C3,..., and Cn-1 is a subclass of Cn. That is, Cn is the most general class, and C1 is the most specific class. In Java, Cn is the Object class. If o invokes a method p, the JVM searches for the implementation of the method p in C1, C2, ..., Cn-1, and Cn, in this order, until it is found. Once an implementation is found, the search stops and the first-found implementation is invoked."

Comment: Что я не так понимаю?

Comment: @panzermarin пытаетесь применить вышеописанную концепцию к приватному методу, которого не существует вне текущего класса.